# How to change elements in the ArrayList to a different object type?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, parseint

I have an `ArrayList<Character>`. How do I change the elements inside the array into integers? The code is in Java.

Example:

```
private ArrayList<Character> arrayList;
```

I tried `Integer.parseInt()` like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(arrayList, arrayList.get(0));
```

But the `parseInt` only works for strings.

Comment: if u want to dynamically use reflection it will do for all types.

Comment: I never heard of dynamically use reflection. Please elaborate. =]

Comment: if you dont know type of the object comes which is to be casted to Int then first find its type dynamically then pass related method or block to typecast as Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well looking at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), you could just use `.charValue()` and cast it to an int

```
(int)(arrayList.get(0).charValue());
```

Comment: +1 ignore my earlier comment about sign extending. `char` primitives are zero-extended on a widening conversion (sec 5.1.2 in the JLS).

Comment: For some reason the type cast does not work but if I omit the int data type and assign the content to an integer variable it works!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a character to int while the `parseInt` method works only for Strings. Try this:

```
Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0).toString());
```

Comment: I get a NumberFormatException. =/

Comment: What's your input and the complete ArrayList just before the exception?

Comment: For input string: "[-, x, ^, 2, +, 2, x, -, 1, =, 0]" It is a polynomial read from a file. Each arraylist holds an unique polynomial.

Comment: I will find another way. Turns out to be tougher than I imagine.

Comment: There's one thing you can do. Traverse over the ArrayList, check each character if it's numeric, if it is, then cast it to int. Are you looking to change all numeric characters in the arraylist to int? Do you want to convert those into a new arraylist? Please answer these so I can write new code and post it here.